# Windows 8: error when trying to create new user

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

When I try to create a new user  the Settings app, at the end of the process I get an error that says:

**We're sorry, but something went wrong. This user wasn't added to this PC. Code: 0x8007089a**

I created a user a few days ago without any problem. I've also installed all available updates for W8 but still have the problem.

I've already googled this issue without any real way of solving it. Any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you still experience the issue after rebooting?

Comment: @David yes, I've rebooted several times

Comment: I cannot find anything on that error code, nor have I experienced this issue before. Have you using any weird characters in the user name?

Comment: @David: got it!!!! It was a problem for adding a period in the name!!!! I can't believe that Windows can't detect that and give a warning about it instead some random error message... anyways thank you for suggesting that!

Comment: You're very welcome for the suggestion. If you like, you could accept my answer (click the check mark next to the answer) which would point out the correct answer and give the person with the suggestion credit for their suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using a period in the name of the user, without it I can create it with no problem...

Comment: your problem is about "The specified username is invalid". you can find it here: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH12638

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are not using an special characters or punctuation in the username as this will cause the username to be considered invalid.

Comment: From winerror.h: 0x8007089a = ERROR_BAD_USERNAME - "The specified username is invalid."